# What exactly did the 7 keys do at the end of the Magician King?

Tags: lev-grossman, magician-king

I just finished reading "Magician King" by Lev Grossman, but I didn't really get what the 7 keys did.

Since they were trying to

> stop the gods from "fixing" the world and taking the magic back form mortal beings.

How exactly did the keys do that? And what's even more interesting, where did the keys come from? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for where the 7 keys came from, I believe that somewhere in the *Magicians* series (I can't find the reference) somebody remarks that some things, like the Questing Beast, are magically created when a world is created, even though the creator of the world didn't explicitly wish for them. I expect the seven keys fall into this category.

So possibly they were created by magic for the purpose of keeping magic from being destroyed. In some twisted way, this actually makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, that is a very interesting interpretation :) It'll probably do, unless there is some other cannon answer, but I don't think there is.

Comment: We may learn more in the final book.

Comment: ... or (now that I've read it) we may not.